# How to struct yaml file in parent child order?

Tags: go, struct, yaml

I want to form a struct using golang via yaml file but I find it difficult to figure out to do it.

```
api:
  local:
    host: localhost
    port: 8085
  develop:
    host:
    port:
  production:
    host:
    port:
rest-api:
  local:
    host: localhost
    port: 8085
  develop:
    host:
    port:
  production:
    host:
    port:
```

this is the format in my yaml file

the expected code of this is i want to create a dynamic api url in local, develop and production format like api : local = host+port, same to develop and production to dynamically configure it easily and set up

Would appreciate your help in golang struct and also for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This online resource will get you halfway there:

https://mengzhuo.github.io/yaml-to-go/

Pasting your yaml yields this:

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
    API struct {
        Local struct {
            Host string `yaml:"host"`
            Port int    `yaml:"port"`
        } `yaml:"local"`
        Develop struct {
            Host interface{} `yaml:"host"`
            Port interface{} `yaml:"port"`
        } `yaml:"develop"`
        Production struct {
            Host interface{} `yaml:"host"`
            Port interface{} `yaml:"port"`
        } `yaml:"production"`
    } `yaml:"api"`
    RestAPI struct {
        Local struct {
            Host string `yaml:"host"`
            Port int    `yaml:"port"`
        } `yaml:"local"`
        Develop struct {
            Host interface{} `yaml:"host"`
            Port interface{} `yaml:"port"`
        } `yaml:"develop"`
        Production struct {
            Host interface{} `yaml:"host"`
            Port interface{} `yaml:"port"`
        } `yaml:"production"`
    } `yaml:"rest-api"`
}
```

There's obvious sub-type duplicates. So it can be trimmed.

**First pass:**

```
type Address struct {
    Host string `yaml:"host"`
    Port int    `yaml:"port"`
}

type MyConfig struct {
    API struct {
        Local      Address `yaml:"local"`
        Develop    Address `yaml:"develop"`
        Production Address `yaml:"production"`
    } `yaml:"api"`
    RestAPI struct {
        Local      Address `yaml:"local"`
        Develop    Address `yaml:"develop"`
        Production Address `yaml:"production"`
    } `yaml:"rest-api"`
}
```

**Second (and final) pass:**

```
type Address struct {
    Host string `yaml:"host"`
    Port int    `yaml:"port"`
}

type Deployment struct {
    Local      Address `yaml:"local"`
    Develop    Address `yaml:"develop"`
    Production Address `yaml:"production"`
}

type MyConfig struct {
    API     Deployment `yaml:"api"`
    RestAPI Deployment `yaml:"rest-api"`
}
```